# jquery datatable with asp.net mvc data not loading

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatable, datatables, smartadmin

Hi on my project i'm using jquery datatable. my question is i tried to load the table using ajax request but i failed. after several attempt please help me to get through this.

my datatable initializing was

```
var responsiveHelperDatatableColReorder = undefined;
$('#tbl_datasource').dataTable({
    sDom: '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">',
    iDisplayLength: -1,
    searching: false,
    ordering: false,
    scrollY: 300,
    scrollX: true,
    info: false,
    paging: false,
    "preDrawCallback": function () {
        // Initialize the responsive datatables helper once.
        if (!responsiveHelperDatatableColReorder) {
            responsiveHelperDatatableColReorder = new ResponsiveDatatablesHelper($('#tbl_datasource'), {
                tablet: 1024,
                phone: 480
            });
        }
    },
    "rowCallback": function (nRow) {
        responsiveHelperDatatableColReorder.createExpandIcon(nRow);
    },
    "drawCallback": function (oSettings) {
        responsiveHelperDatatableColReorder.respond();
    },
    ajax: {
        url : '../Home/DataSourceHealth',
        dataType: "json"
    },
    columns: [
        { "data": "providerName" },
        { "data": "fileName" },
        { "data": "status" },
        { "data": "lastRunTime" },
        { "data": "avgRecords" },
        { "data": "numberOfRecordes" },
        { "data": "numberOfErrorRecords" }
    ]
});
```

i use smartadmin admin template on my view

```
<table id="tbl_datasource" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-class="expand">Name</th>
            <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Source File</th>
            <th data-hide="phone">Loading status</th>
            <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Last run time</th>
            <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Avg. records</th>
            <th data-hide="phone,tablet">No.of records</th>
            <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Deviation</th>
            <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Data status</th>
            <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

on my controller i returned json object in this format

```
[
  {
    "loadDetailId": 108,
    "loadDetailStatusId": 7,
    "providerName": "Marin",
    "status": "Complete File Process",
    "fileName": "SiSenseChryslerPAPCanadaByClientAccount_03042015_bk8heq3q70.csv",
    "numberOfRecordes": 633,
    "avgRecords": 633.00,
    "numberOfErrorRecords": 3,
    "lastRunTime": "2015-03-10T15:01:40.14"
  },
  {
    "loadDetailId": 109,
    "loadDetailStatusId": 7,
    "providerName": "Marin",
    "status": "Complete File Process",
    "fileName": "SiSenseCPAPDisplayCampaigns_03042015_nqh8w254o2.csv",
    "numberOfRecordes": 100003,
    "avgRecords": 100001.00,
    "numberOfErrorRecords": 3,
    "lastRunTime": "2015-03-10T15:01:42.283"
  }
]
```

what was i missed when configuring jquery datatable?

**updated**

i have found the initial problem it was data structure should be like this

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "loadDetailId": 108,
      "loadDetailStatusId": 7,
      "providerName": "Marin",
      "status": "Complete File Process",
      "fileName": "SiSenseChryslerPAPCanadaByClientAccount_03042015_bk8heq3q70.csv",
      "numberOfRecordes": 633,
      "avgRecords": 633.00,
      "numberOfErrorRecords": 3,
      "lastRunTime": "2015-03-10T15:01:40.14"
    },
    {
      "loadDetailId": 109,
      "loadDetailStatusId": 7,
      "providerName": "Marin",
      "status": "Complete File Process",
      "fileName": "SiSenseCPAPDisplayCampaigns_03042015_nqh8w254o2.csv",
      "numberOfRecordes": 100003,
      "avgRecords": 100001.00,
      "numberOfErrorRecords": 3,
      "lastRunTime": "2015-03-10T15:01:42.283"
    }
 ]
}
```

but still having issue here is the firebug screenshot

[image]

thanks

Comment: run your site on firefox with firebug enabled and check the console.. any js erros thrown? also add a break point on your action method that returns the json does it get called correctly, run fiddler and check the response of the call .. all looks good?. I am not familiar with jquery datatable function, but if you do check my comments they might give you a clue or help you enhance the question so others can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of things that could be going wrong here. First, if your returned JSON is not named `data` then you have to change your datatables initialization to add `datasrc = ""` property to it like so:

```
ajax: {
    url : '../Home/DataSourceHealth',
    dataType: "json",
    dataSrc: ""
}
```

This makes datatables read in array of objects like the one that is returned in your case. Otherwise it looks for an object named `data` which when it doesn't find one, it assumes there is no data. Here is the documentation for this: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc

Second problem with your datatables is that you have more headers than the data that you're reading in through your columns:

9 headers:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-class="expand">Name</th>
        <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Source File</th>
        <th data-hide="phone">Loading status</th>
        <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Last run time</th>
        <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Avg. records</th>
        <th data-hide="phone,tablet">No.of records</th>
        <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Deviation</th>
        <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Data status</th>
        <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

7 data columns defined:

```
columns: [
    { "data": "providerName" },
    { "data": "fileName" },
    { "data": "status" },
    { "data": "lastRunTime" },
    { "data": "avgRecords" },
    { "data": "numberOfRecordes" },
    { "data": "numberOfErrorRecords" }
]
```

The number of headers and data columns needs to be exactly the same or it will not work.

Answer (score -1):

try to debug with chrome or IE and look what error you get for your request.

Also try this

```
ajax: {
url : '/Home/DataSourceHealth',
dataType: "json"
},
```

Comment: that was not a issue.. i'm getting data to client side properly. problem comes when table rendering. thanks